# Initialized integer to be called as the value of the index of a charAt, however I can't decrease the value of the index integer

Tags: java

I'm practicing Java on Codesignal.com, however, I've honestly understand java much less than I'd like to. The objective is to determine if the given string is a palindrome. To do this, the intent of my code is to read each character of the given string and copy it into a reversed string, then compare the strings to find if they are identical.

According to CodeSignal, at line 8 it expects a semi-colon; however, one already exists there, and I've tried every solution I could come up with, I might just be misunderstanding syntax. Below is my current code, I'd appreciate any assistance whatsoever, thank you.

Code:

```
boolean checkPalindrome(String inputString) {
    String reverseString = 0;
    int x = inputString.length;
    int b = inputString.length;
    for (int i = 0; i > x; i++) {
        char a = str.charAt(b);
        int b - 1;
        String reverseString = reverseString + "a";
    }
    if (reverseString == inputString) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The error message displayed is:

> ```
> file.java on line 8: error: ';' expected
>        int b - 1;
>        1 error
> ```

Comment: what you intended to execute with `int b - 1;`? `b--`?

Comment: Also, please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java before asking your next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only decreasing the value of `b`, there are several more errors in your code for which it will never be compiled successfully. Actually, the whole code is full of errors. I am pointing out the errors one by one but one suggestion for you, try to learn the fundamentals of JAVA programming properly before getting your hand dirty on actual problem solving.

---

**1.**

> `String reverseString = 0;`

You should get compilation error with that line as int cannot be converted to String.

The correct syntax can be like this:

```
String reverseString = "";
```

---

**2.**

> `int x = inputString.length;`

In Java, `length` variable is applicable for arrays whereas, for strings, `length()` method do the same.

So, the fix is:

```
int x = inputString.length();
```

---

**3.**

> `int b = inputString.length;`

As you are fetching `charAt(b)` later on your code, you'll get `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. As indexing in `charAt()` starts from 0 and ends at string_length - 1.

So, correction is:

```
int b = x;
```

---

**4.**

> `for (int i = 0; i > x; i++)`

Completely wrong logic, check at the condition properly. `i > x` means the loop will not proceed further at all. So, it should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
```

---

**5.**

> `int b - 1;`

Blatantly wrong syntax. If you want to decrement the variable value, you don't need the `int` before doing every operation with already declared variable. And so, the correct syntax can be:

```
b = b - 1;
```

Or, Simply:

```
b--;
```

---

**6.**

> `String reverseString = reverseString + "a";`

Once I've told you should use data type for a variable once during declaration. And also `"a"` is simply a string here. For getting the variable value, you should have used just `a`, not with `""`. So, the fix is:

```
reverseString = reverseString + a;
```

---

**7.**

> ```
> if (reverseString == inputString) {
>     return false;
> }
> else {
>     return true;
> }
> ```

First thing is, we don't compare string equality in java using `==` sign. That is because `==` just compares the object not the actual contents inside the string. In this case, you have to use `.equals()` method. Another thing is, as your method name is `checkPalindrome()`, ideally it should return true when it is palindrome and false when it is not. But, you are doing it reverse. IDK, may be you are handling this properly as a reverse manner also inside your `main()` or from where you are calling this method.

So, the correction will be:

```
if (reverseString.equals(inputString))
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

---

**So, That's all**

The full method will be like this:

```
boolean checkPalindrome(String inputString) {
    String reverseString = "";
    int x = inputString.length();
    int b = x;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        char a = inputString.charAt(b);
        b--;
        reverseString = reverseString + a;
    }
    if (reverseString.equals(inputString))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

The code can be further simplified to this:

```
boolean checkPalindrome(String inputString) {
    String reverseString = "";
    int x = inputString.length();
    for (int i = x - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        reverseString += inputString.charAt(i);
    if (reverseString.equals(inputString))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Your breakdown of each error individually helped me immensely as it explained each mistake or issue and showed a better way to execute it. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 2):

Fixing the syntax error is fairly simple. You already told Java you want to create a variable named `b` at the line `int b = inputString.length;`, so when it sees `int b - 1;` Java thinks you are trying to make a new variable named `b`. I assume you want to subtract one from `b`, to do this change the line to `b = b - 1;`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare variable more than once `int b =`

If you want to decrease `b` value just use `--` as post-[decrement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)

```
b--;
```

Or pre-decrement

```
--b;
```

> -- Decrement operator; decrements a value by 1